# Bundle virtual/conda environment for EMR bootstrap

Tags: python, anaconda, bootstrapping, emr

I have been using Anaconda Python a lot but also have made many package upgrades (like PANDAS).  I've written some tools that I want to turn into a MapReduce job and I've researched how to go about the python EMR bootstrapping for package dependencies.

I thought about a possible workaround: just getting and installing the Anaconda distribution.  But then I remembered that I'd have to do all the necessary upgrading.

My last effort in possibly making this easy is this question: is there a way to "rebundle" the upgraded anaconda (or one its environments) so that it can be stored on S3 and used as in the EMR bootstrap action?

Thanks for any help!

ADDED:  I suppose it would require a license to be able to wrap up an Anaconda distro like this and use it on various machines, be they in my office network or on AWS.  Here's an open source version of this question (I just learned the main package manager to the Anaconda distro is actually OS):

Suppose I have a virtual (or conda) environment running with various modules and extensions installed.  What is the proper way, if any, to encapsulate/bundle this virtual environment so that I can efficiently deploy it as needed?  I have come across 'pip bundle' and there is 'conda clone' and 'conda create' as well.  Also, there appears the concept of conda channels.  It's just not clear to me if I can put these together for efficient deployment on EMR and if so, how.

Answer (score 0):

The [license](http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/eula.html) allows you to do this, if that's what you're asking.

You might also look at http://continuum.io/anaconda-cluster and http://continuumio.github.io/conda-cluster/.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to Conda Cluster.  I added an extra part to my question since you made a good point about the license.